# Vulkan and glfw - glfwVulkanSupported() always return false

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

I'm trying to run a basic Vulkan test using GLFW3.2 :

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (glfwVulkanSupported())
    {
        std::cout << "vulkan supported !" << std::endl;

    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "vulkan NOT supported !" << std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which i build using the following cmake :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(vktest)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++-4.9")

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})

message("kek")
message(${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(${Vulkan_LIBRARIES})
message(${Vulkan_LIBRARY})

add_executable(vktest vulkanTest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(vktest ${Vulkan_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(vktest glfw)
```

Building this works just fine.

But when i run the program i always get in the else statement.

I installed nvidia last driver, lunarg's vulkan sdk with the following 
environment variables :

```
export VULKAN_SDK=/home/mathias/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.42.2/x86_64
set PATH $VULKAN_SDK/bin $PATH
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH $VULKAN_SDK/lib $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
set VK_LAYER_PATH $VULKAN_SDK/etc/explicit_layer.d
```

Besides i can run the cube example.

Any idea of why it never returns true ?

Answer (score 6):

You are probably missing a `glfwInit()` call.

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <cassert>
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    bool success =  glfwInit();  //< Important! 
    assert(success);
    if(glfwVVulkanSupported()) {
        puts("Success!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Generally, the only glfw function you should call before glfwInit() is `glfwSetErrorCallback`. (There may be other exceptions, but none that I am aware of.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing #define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN , does it not?

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN //as required by GLFW
#include "vulkan\vk_cpp.hpp" 
#include "GLFW\glfw3.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit()) //Initialize GLFW
    {
        std::cout << "GLFW not initialized.\n";
        abort();
    }
    if (!glfwVulkanSupported()) //Any Vulkan-related function requires GLFW initialized
    {
        std::cout << "Vulkan not supported.\n";
        abort();
    }
    uint32_t ext_count; // an output placeholder
    auto ext_list = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&ext_count);

    std::copy(&ext_list[0], &ext_list[ext_count-1], std::ostream_iterator<const char *>(cout, "\n"));

    //feed extension list into InstanceCreateInfo struct in prepare for Vulkan instance creation
    vk::InstanceCreateInfo ifo{ vk::InstanceCreateFlags(), nullptr, 0, nullptr, ext_count, ext_list };
    glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API); // Comment out this if you need OpenGL also
    GLFWwindow* hWnd = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Foobar", NULL, NULL); // The usual window
    auto inst = vk::createInstance(ifo); // Vulkan instance creation
    vk::SurfaceKHR surf{};
    auto psurf = VkSurfaceKHR(surf); // you can cast vk::* object to Vk* using a type cast
    auto r = glfwCreateWindowSurface(VkInstance(inst), hWnd, NULL, &psurf); //VK_SUCCESS is somehow...0
    // Draw stuff here

    // Finish drawing
    vkDestroySurfaceKHR((VkInstance)inst, VkSurfaceKHR(surf), nullptr);//vkcpp seems have no destructor for surface object
    glfwDestroyWindow(hWnd); //Destroy the surface before the window
    glfwTerminate(); // Free GLFW resource
    return 0;
}
```

if there are typos in this code free to fix them. I have no way to compile it at current location

Comment: The glfw documentation tells to either define the macro as you did, or either include the vulkan header before the glfw header. For some reason i first tried the second one, but only defining the macro seems to work. So it's all good for me, thanks !

Comment: @Mathias it might be implementation depending. ThisAPI is very young and there might be versions that require workarounds. Similarly, in older VIsual Studio libraries, to make strings properly work with  iostream, one had  include <string> after the <iostream> header.. that was fixed. I used older Khronos'  project vulkan-hpp header, that probably was the only way back then.